# Google Drive SDK: Can Chrome extension and Android app share the same private app folder?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Android app using Google Drive API, can create a private folder in the users Google Drive storage, visible only to this Android app, where it can store and read back files.

Similarly, a Google Chrome Extension can create and use its own private app folder, visible only to this extension, and nothing else.

However my Android app and Google Chrome extension are part of the same product, and it would be ideal if they could share the same private folder - both could read and write there. At this time to achieve this goal I have to give both Android app and Chrome extension broad permissions to the entire user's Google Drive storage area, and create a public folder, which is not ideal.

For more info on the private appDataFolder see https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way for the 2 apps to have the same `appFolder`. As you already indicated, your respective Chrome and Android apps have their own `appFolder` and they can't access each other's files. Do note that the `appFolder` is designed to be used to store application data, which may vary for Chrome and Android.

Try out if Service Accounts could work for you. But, from how I understand how your app might work, you'd still want the user to have access to those files. If this is correct, Service Account will likely be out as an alternative.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer! I thought that maybe there is a trick like sharing the same API key or Oauth credential in both apps, but apparently it's not possible.